# Login User To Web Application if User Logged In in Dekstop Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, single-sign-on

### Scenario:

I have a desktop application which is working fine with its database from where we authenticate user using **Username** and **Password**, we have a web application that also requires same credentials for logging in.

What i want to achieve is if User is already logged in on Desktop application,  i need to skip the Login part on Web Application when user opens it. Web Application gets launched in browser from a button inside my Desktop application using `Process.Start()` thing.

One way that is is my mind is to pass username password in query string and using java-script putting username and password in fields and posting form programmatically but it is not safe as user can save username password from query string and can use it on any system to login which is not secure.

Any thoughts on it what are my option to do this type of thing?

Comment: You are probably looking for Single Sign On
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

Comment: how about sharing cookie between desktop and web application. Create a cookie from eighter of desktop or web and then when app start just check for existance and then use those credential or token to authrize.

Comment: @JSJ any useful link for that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the username and password in a query string. Instead generate a token that can be used for a one-time login that is stored in the database. Make sure tokens expire if they haven't been used in e.g. 8 hours. When you start the website, pass the token on the query string to the website. Then the website uses the token to connect the user's session to their account, and the token gets deleted.